# FFMPEG running in Command Line but not PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg build for windows to make video thumbnails . The command works well in command line but not from PHP exec method. am using PHP 5.2.11

Here is the command.

```
"E:/Documents and Settings/x/WINDOWS/ffmpeg" -itsoffset -4 -v "E:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/bs/files/videogal/c08c3d20eeb9083ed033577bd154cba6.flv" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 "E:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/bs/files/gallery/8ff43b72b932d2a34e7a6733672ad4d6.jpg" 2>&1
```

Can somebody help. I checked the permissions they seem fine. GD is installed.

The error msg is `'E:/Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Am using forward slashes in my paths except when escaping double quotes

The PHP function

```
function ExtractThumb($in, $out)
{$path=dbconf::FFMPEG_PATH;
    $thumb_stdout;
    $errors;
    $retval = 0;
 echo $in;
    // Delete the file if it already exists
    if (file_exists($out)) { unlink($out); }

    // Use ffmpeg to generate a thumbnail from the movie
    $cmd = "$path -itsoffset -4 -i $in -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 $out 2>&1";
   echo $cmd;

   exec($cmd, $thumb_stdout, $retval);

    // Queue up the error for processing
    if ($retval != 0) { $errors[] = "FFMPEG thumbnail generation failed"; }

    if (!empty($thumb_stdout))
    {
        foreach ($thumb_stdout as $line)
        {
            echo $line . "\n";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($errors))
    {
        foreach ($errors as $error)
        {
            echo $error . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

funny enough if I run without the $in and $out absolute path this is what I get

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: --extra-cflags=-fno-common --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-avisynth --enable-swscale --enable-gpl libavutil 49.12. 0 / 49.12. 0 libavcodec 52.10. 0 / 52.10. 0 libavformat 52.23. 1 / 52.23. 1 libavdevice 52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0 libswscale 0. 6. 1 / 0. 6. 1 built on Jan 13 2009 02:57:09, gcc: 4.2.4 822ae86a93810dade2843e822390d723.flv: no such file or directory
```

Comment: show how you are executing it with PHP. What error message you have. Are you running it against a web server. If yes, are you allowed to go to `E:\Documents and Settings` ?etc etc. You have to show more info !

Comment: I am using Windows XP so I doubt if there are issues of permissions

Answer (score 4):

```
exec("\"E:\\Documents and Settings\\x\\WINDOWS\\ffmpeg\" -i <inputfile> <options> <outfile>");
```

Here's one of mine I've used in the past (granted I'm on a LAMP stack):

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$in." -y -an -sameq -vframes 1 -s 100x56 -ss 3 -t 0.001 ".$out;
```

You may also consider: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape your command properly:

```
exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $thumb_stdout, $retval);
```

Also do you have PHP safe mode on? 
You should check that `$in` is a real file before trying to encode too.

Comment: +1 for the safe mode on. It may apply default open_basedir limitations that exclude the exec command to reach the ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 1):

are you properly escaping your backslashes, quotes etc.? Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it doesn't recognize it as a command. Its most probably your quoting. Check your quoting of white spaces. Escape the white spaces when necessary using slash "\ ". And where is your code snippet that calls `exec()`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
$cmd = "\"$path\" -itsoffset -4 -i \"$in\" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 \"$out\" 2>&1";
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it this way::

```
exec("C:/wamp/bin/ffmpeg -i ./output4.mp4 -sameq -acodec libmp3lame -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 ./output8.flv -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 4 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 ./pic008.jpg 2>&1");
```

Directly connected from WAMP SERVER.

Notice the:

> ./output4.mp4

That tells PHP that I am dealing with the current directory.

--All the Best