# HTML5 video for iPhone/Safari/iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video

Merry Christmas! The website is made is http://zavinagizaedno.com

I can't figure out how to edit my code and what video formats to include, so when I open the website on my phone (i have an iPhone, used Safari on iOS, but never tried a different browser on iOS or Android)
I can see the HTML5 video, not the image that substitutes it.

When I open it on PC/Mac, not matter which browser everything is perfect (video plays). When I try on iPhone via Safari - video does not show.
I have included mp4/m4v/3gp/ and two more, but no luck so far. Help me out!

Comment: first up, video seems really slow to load on PC, check this answer for more info on optimizing it for web https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383, secondly auto-play video on mobile devices is a bit complex (for instance iOS has only just started to allow it, needs `webkit-playsinline` and video must be muted, third I'd put the mp4 first (but that's just me)

Comment: Your website is 26.7mb, perhaps you might want to optimize not only video but images as well.

Answer (score 0):

i can probaly help you with this. Convert the video to GIF format and put the GIF on the website.
If the video is very large, the GIF should display a bit slow, but it will 100% work.
More help: Try out gifs.com, upload your video and when done copy direct link and use the following code:
< img src= "(your direct link)" >
Hope it helps you.