# html5 video on internet explorer

Tags: html, video

i have a problem.
I want to show my video on the page, but it doesn't work on IE 11 windows 7, on other it works fine. The problem is that other mp4 files works on IE 11, windows 7 too.

I don't know what is wrong with my video file that IE 11, windows 7 shows nothing

```
<div class="my-video">
<div class="my-video-overlay"></div>
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
<source src="http://megasystem.freshdraft.pl/wp-content/themes/x/video/megasys.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://megasystem.freshdraft.pl/wp-content/themes/x/video/megasys.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://megasystem.freshdraft.pl/wp-content/themes/x/video/megasys.ogv" type="video/ogv">
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that you want to use webm. That ain't supported by IE11 yet. https://caniuse.com/#search=video

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383 for how to use ffmpeg to re-encode your video if the format of the mp4 is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems to like a no Media Feature installed into your PC (Win-7).Install from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16546
Video worked fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc, because these browsers can support webm file also.

Comment: It's not the problem because if I place only mp4 file it doesn't work too. If I swap it to another mp4 file it works.

Comment: Ok, Convert your megasys.ogv or webm to mp4 and check if this is working? You can use any online tool for this.

Comment: I have mp4 file: <source src="http://megasystem.freshdraft.pl/wp-content/themes/x/video/megasys.mp4" type="video/mp4"> and it's not working, other mp4 files works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, but other mp4 files, which i tested plays on ie 11 windows 7 too. I think the problem must be with my video and I want to solve it (convert this video or something...)