# Video tag not playing in safari for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, video, safari, mp4

I know this question's come up a lot but I've not found a working solution as yet.

I am trying to embed a simple video in HTML5 for a website I'm working on.

The video just does not want to load in safari on any iphone.

I have tried three different mp4 formats and the .mov format and so far no luck.

My embed tag is as follows:

```
<video width="360" height="" controls>
            <source src="video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/2.mov" type="video/mov">
            <source src="video/3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

Video works just fine in chrome on android and on PC. I only two apple devices, an iPhone SE and an iPhone 6. So far no luck.

Please note that the content of the above four videos are identical, just encoded and named differently.

Thanks

James

Comment: can you share the actual mp4 (you probably only want one in the tag) ... my guess is going to be an encoding issue - see something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383 (you may also want to add a `-c:a libfaac` to force audio to a supported format)

Comment: For privacy and copyright I am afraid I cant, but the video is less than 1 meg, has no audio and loads just fine on an android device. The .mov encoded versions loads up just fine on PC too. What I am getting on iPhone safari is the 'play' icon which you can tap over and over but the video simply will not load.