# Optimizing HTML5 Video with size

Tags: html, performance, video, performance-testing

Does the file size of a video, hosted externally and embedded using  tag with an absolute url, affect load time or performance? There are multiple (5-10) videos on the page, none of which autoplay.

I have tried to keep the videos under 10 mb in file size, but doing so severely hurts the quality of the video. Does a video hosted on another server and not locally or using a relative url, even impact speed and performance of the page?

Comment: Yes. Larger files take longer to download.

Comment: The files I have are for fairly short videos of just a few seconds, but suppose I want to have very long 30 minute videos. Not sure there is any amount of optimization that can get it down to 9 or 10 mb. In that case do I just have to accept the compromised performance or quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes. The size of your video file will make a difference.
There are a number of things you can do using a tool such as `ffmpeg` to improve that though - moving the metadata to the start of the file (helps it start playing and seek without having to download the whole file) and optimizing for a particular bitrate

See [HTML5 video not streaming and taking 90 seconds to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383) for some specific suggestions