# HTML5 video not autoplaying?

Tags: android, html, video

This is driving me NUTS!

I have simple HTML5 video player that won't autoplay on Android.

Here a sample. This WON`T autoplay

```
<video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="./image/stories/boomerang_stories.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your browser does not support the video element.</p>
</video>
```

http://franco.gcj.io/index2.html

The bizarre thing is, it's the same code from here, and this one works.

```
<video autoplay muted loop>
   <source src="chrome-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <p>Your browser does not support the video element.</p>
</video>
```

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/muted-autoplay/

Am I missing something really obvious? The only variable I can think about is the video size.

Comment: As you are saying that its not autoplaying. Is it playing when you manually play it ?

Comment: And also post your code here. Thats important.

Comment: @AsutoshPanda yes, exactly.

Comment: If I scroll the second instance into view it does play. If you resize the `video` element to better fit the browser page does it play? Also on desktop or mobile it loads very slowly. Have you optimized the video for web playback eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383