# HTML5 Progressive Video downloadding

Tags: html5-video

I have to make a video gallery in HTML5. I also use symfony 3.4 in my project. I use the HTML5 tag  to display video on my page. There is a sample:

```
<video controls preload="auto" poster="{{ asset('img/poster.jpg') }}" width="100%">
    <source src="{{ asset('video/video1.mp4') }}"  type="video/mp4">
    Your Browser is not supported
</video>
```

The problem is that, I want my video loading while playing and not playing after loading completed

Comment: first thing to try would be to use FFMPEG to make sure the MOOV atom in your MP4 is at the start, not the end - this gives the browser the relevant metadata at the start not the end -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383. Also your server would need to support byte range requests so it can ask for partial downloads of the video to buffer as it plays through

Comment: Thanks you. It works