# PHP Large Video Files Streaming

Tags: php, html, video

I've a website with a private area that currently hosts some videos. This files are relatively small (some MB) and visible to authenticated users only into an html5 video player. I protect them with an .htaccess file. 
Even if this is probably not the best, this way is very simple and does not require relying on expensive external services.
The problem is that now i have to upload a large video file (3 GB) and i think the current way is no longer a good one. 
What is the best option to play large private videos on a website? 
Are there any services (possibly free) that are suitable for me?

Comment: Why would the size of the video make any difference to this

Comment: I ran a test with a 200 mb file and noticed that the loading times increased. I would not like the server to overload with larger files.

Comment: the loading time in the browser may be just that the video needs optimizing for streaming. You could look at converting to something like DASH or HLS, or tweaking the MP4 as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836206/html5-video-not-streaming-and-taking-90-seconds-to-load/40943383#40943383