# Cordova currentTime in HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, video

I'm developing a Cordova app for Android and I need to put a video with some cue points controlled by buttons.

In the HTML, I have the code to load the mp4 file and the buttons. With JS I'm trying to add the cue points on a click event, but any number I put in the currentTime property, always starts from the beginning of the video. Instead of start from the point I have put.

The code I have is:

```
document.getElementById("video").load();
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    document.getElementById("video").play();
    document.getElementById("video").currentTime = seconds;
}, false);
```

I tried to change the order of the lines, because I read something over there but no results.

---

**EDIT:**

Still no results, now I'm with this:

```
document.getElementById("video").currentTime = seconds;
document.getElementById("video").play();
```

But does the same as the others.

Anyone can help?

---

Thanks.

Comment: At first, why do you play the video and then set `currentTime`? Try to set the time before you are playing the video. - Also, on every change you do on your video try to add `.load()` afterwards for the video to update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried and doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you have set 'seconds' to a value? also, is your video optimized for streaming (with the MOOV atom at the front - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937114/set-up-buffering-for-video-object/32959717#32959717 - otherwise it won't be able to seek correctly until it has read to the end of the file)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the frame rate.

The video I was trying initially had 30 and I tried with one of 24 and it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me. Is there another solution?